# Extending Drupal 7 search

Tags: search, drupal-7

I want to extend default Drupal 7 node search with one additional field.

I alter search form with the following new field:

```php
function mymodule_form_search_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['basic']['site'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => array(
            'KEY1' => 'TITLE1',
            'KEY2' => 'TITLE2',
            'KEY3' => 'TITLE3'
        )
    );
}
```

I have a field called `field_data_field_site.field_site_value` which i need to use as a filter in this search.

I've tried to read about `hook_search_*` functions but didn't get the idea.

My question is the following. How can I extend search form? Anyone have live examples?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The following is the best way I solve this problem.

First of all I need to alter Drupal's search block and search form with my field and define new submit function.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'search_form_alter_submit';

    $form['site'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => _options(),
        '#default_value' => (($_GET['site']) ? $_GET['site'] : '')
    );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_search_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'search_form_alter_submit';

    $form['basic']['site'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => _options(),
        '#default_value' => (($_GET['site']) ? $_GET['site'] : '')
    );
}

function _options() {
    return array(
        '' => 'Select site',
        'site-1' => 'Site 1',
        'site-2' => 'Site 2'
    );
}
```

Submit function will forward us to default `search/node` page but with our query. Page would look like `search/node/Our-query-string?site=Our-option-selected`.

```php
function search_form_alter_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $path = $form_state['redirect'];
    $options = array(
        'query' => array(
            'site' => $form_state['values']['site']
        )
    );
    drupal_goto($path, $options);
}
```

Next step is to use `hook_search_info` (Don't forget to turn it on and set as default on `admin/config/search/settings` page).

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_search_info().
 */
function mymodule_search_info() {
    return array(
        'title' => 'Content',
        'path' => 'node',
        'conditions_callback' => '_conditions_callback',
    );
}
```

Conditions callback function defined in `hook_search_info`. We need to provide additional queries to our search.

```php
function _conditions_callback($keys) {
    $conditions = array();
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['site'])) {
        $conditions['site'] = $_REQUEST['site'];
    }
    return $conditions;
}
```

Finally, `hook_search_execute` will filter our content by our query. I used default code from this hook with modifications I need.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_search_execute().
 */
function mymodule_search_execute($keys = NULL, $conditions = NULL) {
    // Build matching conditions
    $query = db_select('search_index', 'i', array('target' => 'slave'))
        ->extend('SearchQuery')
        ->extend('PagerDefault');

    $query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = i.sid');

    // Here goes my filter where I joined another table and
    // filter by required field
    $site = (isset($conditions['site'])) ? $conditions['site'] : NULL;
    if ($site) {
        $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_site', 's', 's.entity_id = i.sid');
        $query->condition('s.field_site_value', $site);
    }
    // End of my filter

    $query
        ->condition('n.status', 1)
        ->addTag('node_access')
        ->searchExpression($keys, 'node');

    // Insert special keywords.
    $query->setOption('type', 'n.type');
    $query->setOption('language', 'n.language');
    if ($query->setOption('term', 'ti.tid')) {
        $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'n.nid = ti.nid');
    }

    // Only continue if the first pass query matches.
    if (!$query->executeFirstPass()) {
        return array();
    }

    // Add the ranking expressions.
    _node_rankings($query);

    // Load results.
    $find = $query
        ->limit(10)
        ->execute();

    $results = array();
    foreach ($find as $item) {
        // Build the node body.
        $node = node_load($item->sid);
        node_build_content($node, 'search_result');
        $node->body = drupal_render($node->content);

        // Fetch comments for snippet.
        $node->rendered .= ' ' . module_invoke('comment', 'node_update_index', $node);
        // Fetch terms for snippet.
        $node->rendered .= ' ' . module_invoke('taxonomy', 'node_update_index', $node);

        $extra = module_invoke_all('node_search_result', $node);

        $results[] = array(
            'link' => url("node/{$item->sid}", array('absolute' => TRUE)),
            'type' => check_plain(node_type_get_name($node)),
            'title' => $node->title,
            'user' => theme('username', array('account' => $node)),
            'date' => $node->changed,
            'node' => $node,
            'extra' => $extra,
            'score' => $item->calculated_score,
            'snippet' => search_excerpt($keys, $node->body)
        );
    }

    return $results;
}
```

### I'd be happy if anyone would give me a better answer.