# Search with custom condition

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-search

How can I add a condition to default search module?

I want to add a checkbox field called "Allow to search" to nodes, and unchecked items will not show in search results.

[Extending Drupal 7 search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575289/extending-drupal-7-search) seems to be my solution, but I can't make it work; `hook_search_execute()` is not executed.

Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: You did change the 'hook' in 'hook_search_execute' to the name of your module didn't you?

Comment: When I submit search, only hook_search_info() runs, but not hook_search_execute().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first select your module on admin/config/search/settings, and possibly unselect the Node module in the "Active search modules." If your module is not selected there, your hook will not invoked.

> [image: screenshot]

As for the reason why one hook is invoked, and one is not invoke, the code executed by [search_get_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_get_info/7) (the function called from [search_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_menu/7) to build the search menu) first invokes every implementation of `hook_search_info()`, and then it checks for which modules the search integration has been enabled. Since your module doesn't have the search integration enabled, `hook_search_execute()` for your module will never be invoked.

```
  if (!isset($search_hooks)) {
    foreach (module_implements('search_info') as $module) {
      $search_hooks[$module] = call_user_func($module . '_search_info');
      // Use module name as the default value.
      $search_hooks[$module] += array(
        'title' => $module,
        'path' => $module,
      );
      // Include the module name itself in the array.
      $search_hooks[$module]['module'] = $module;
    }
  }

  if ($all) {
    return $search_hooks;
  }

  $active = variable_get('search_active_modules', array('node', 'user'));
  return array_intersect_key($search_hooks, array_flip($active));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's my solution!